# Is it possible to read a console content?

Tags: c#, console

Is is possible for a c# exe program to read the text in the console which it is launched from, displayed *before* the exe is runned ?

Exemple:

```
c:\>dir

25/07/2014  15:49    <REP>          Admin
27/06/2014  08:54                28 t.bat
14/05/2014  16:29    <REP>          Tracing
21/07/2014  09:35    <REP>          Videos
          3 fichier(s)            6 046 octets
          16 Rép(s)  122 432 233 472 octets libres

c:\>myexe.exe
```

Then, myexe.exe will be able to access to the output generated by the dir command (or whatever program output ...).

I guess, via the windows API, I need to get some console informations and then eventually get the console buffer, or something like that ...

Comment: `I guess, via the windows API, I need to get some console informations and then eventually get the console buffer, or something like that ...`  You don't want to do that.  If your executable is dependent on that information then you should *pass that information to your executable as input* rather than having that executable try to open that giant can of worms.

Comment: Would normal input redirection work for you? `c:\> dir | myexe.exe`

Comment: please read the question ... "why do you need that?" : who matters ?

Answer (score 2):

.NET does not provide this functionality directly.  You'll have to use [`ReadConsoleOutput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684965(v=vs.85).aspx) in conjunction with [`GetStdHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231(v=vs.85).aspx).  This will not work if the standard output is currently re-directed.